# Tensorflow Hub module reuse

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-hub

Say I want to use a specific `module` (text embeddings) from TF Hub to create two distinct `models`, that I would then like to export and serve.

**Option 1:**
Import the `module` for each `model`, put each classifier on top, and export 2 `models`; serve each in its own docker container. These `models` contain both the underlying embedding module and the classifier.

**Option 2:**
Serve the `module` itself, and have its output go to 2 different served `models`, that themselves do not contain the embeddings. (Is this even possible?)

My computer science background tells me that **option 2** is better, since we are re-using the original embeddings module for both models, also decoupling the models themselves from the embeddings module.

However, from a practical standpoint, when a data scientist is coding, they are importing the `module` and training with the classifier on top of it, so it becomes cumbersome having to export the `model` itself without the underlying embeddings.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Hopefully my question makes sense, I am not a data scientist myself, I am coming more from a development background.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting a classifier on top of an embedding module creates a fairly strong dependency: the classifier must be trained to the particular embedding space. Unless you make very special arrangements, just swapping in another embedding module won't work. So Option 1 is quite good: it yields two models that can be served and updated independently. They have some overlap, akin to two statically linked programs using the same library, but the source code is still modular: using Hub embedding modules through their common signature makes them interchangeable.

Option 2, by comparison, gives you three moving parts with non-trivial dependencies. If your goal is simplicity, I wouldn't go there.